# how to find a password in string when it has no policy

Tags: java, passwords

I trying to avoid printing password in log. So in my log formatter class i search for a word "password" and then i trying to replace the value of password by *****'s. But now i m facing a issue like how to find the password when i have no password policy. 
MY CODE is :

```
class SecurityEnhancedLogFormatter {
private static final String[] keys= new String[] { "password", "pswrd" }; //No I18N
public String restrictPasswordEntry(String message){
    for(Object object : SENSITIVE_KEY_HASH_SET){
        String str = (String)object;
        while(true){
            if(message.contains(str)){
                int index = message.indexOf(str) - 1;
                message = message.replace(message.substring(index,message.indexOf(",",index)-1),"*****");
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return message;
}
```

in this how to find my password endindex when these passwords have no policy.
That is for String "password" : jkd kjdd,  kdjk*;'.,(this is example, the format can b anything)

Comment: what is the difference between a string with password policy and one without?

Comment: I think this is bound to fail. Either you know all passwords and can hence replace them (in which case, what do you do if a password is a common word or could otherwise occur as regular communication?), or you don't, in which case I don't see how that would be possible at all. But maybe I'm missing something. Or misunderstanding the whole question.

Comment: Wait, I think now I understand - the password *always* occurs right after the string `"password" :`, is that it? Maybe you can reword your question so it becomes a bit more clear.

Comment: Please say this is for a hobby project and not a production system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going down the wrong rabbit hole here.

You do not want to *hope* to find password used in arbitrary messages. Because chances are: your expectations about patterns break at some point.

The real point: don't try to use "technology" to solve a social problem.

Meaning: **educate** your team about reasonable rules regarding logging of passwords.

Like rule no. 1: *never ever log passwords*. Thus: sit down together; understand the problem; and make sure everybody agrees on the problem; and the solution that you want to put in place.

If at all; you would be looking into technology to treat **passwords** really special. For example by giving them their own class; and that class could *overwrite* `toString()` for example to make sure that you always "mask" your passwords; even somebody happens to do

```
log("whatever: " + ... + password);
```

Edit on the comment: when you use a **special** class for passwords (not String!) then you can make sure that at least printing a map or list with those values will always result in an "****" string instead of clear text. 
And please note: you *can* choose to put a method like `getPasswordAsClearText()` to your own class (there might be a need for that) - but then you make it at least *obvious* what will happen here!

In other words: you want to make the Java type system **work** for you. Your approach is to use flat raw strings all over the place, and then "later on", after the facts you try to re-build "meta information" by hoping to find patterns within those flat raw strings.

Comment: Actually the thing is for debugging we might use printing properties hashmaps etc., if in case anyone without knowledge printing the properties/anything which has password  in log will be a problem right?. so i have to avoid those. In logger all kind of datasets will be printed as string so i want to handle it.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree on treating passwords separately; overwriting their `toString()` method is a very nice idea. Even better, of course, would be if the passwords would vanish as a hash in a database once entered and never occur in plain text ever again. But we don't know enough context.

Comment: @sera Passing passwords around in the system like regular data is always the wrong choice. Trying to fix insecure design with a solution like this is like putting band-aid on a shotgun wound. The name `SecurityEnhancedLogFormatter` is a misnomer, as the system obviously has critical security issues.

Comment: @Kayaman thanks for your inputs. this my fun time coding, i just trying to get solution for some of the worst case scenarios :)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you mean by 'password policy' in this context, or why you think it would make any difference, but the problem with this code is that `String.replace()` returns a *new* `String`, and you are throwing it away, so it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are passing passwords around as `String` objects, rather than as `char[]`? Using the latter would avoid this problem, as you'd get nothing meaningful in the logs.

[Why is char[] preferred over String for passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords?rq=1)

Comment: Not necessarily. Somebody might be "clever enough" to use Arrays.toString() for that very array. Yes, using char arrays is a good practice; but **not** for this reason.